# Homotopy orbit spaces of representation spheres

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, rt.representation-theory, homotopy-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and $V$ be finite-dimensional real representation of $G$.  Write $S^V$ for the one-point compactification of $V$, with induced $G$-action, viewed as a pointed space, and consider the homotopy orbit space $(S^V)_{hG}$.  For instance, if $V$ is the regular representation of $G=\mathbb{Z}/2$, $(S^V)_{hG}$ works out to be the suspension of $B\mathbb{Z}/2$.  Is there some kind of general description of this space, presumably built out of classifying spaces of subgroups of $G$?  What if I only care about the stable homotopy type?  I'm most interested in the permutation representations of the symmetric groups.

Answer (score 9):

The most salient fact about (S<sup>V</sup>)<sub>hG</sub> is that it is the Thom space of a vector bundle over BG.  So this gives you a lot of control over the sorts of things seen by homology: e.g., a Thom isomorphism if the bundle is oriented with respect to your homology theory; if you put a CW-structure on BG, then (S<sup>V</sup>)<sub>hG</sub> has a CW-structure with cells in the same dimensions (shifted up by dim V).  Morally, it's a "twisted suspension" of BG, and that fact encodes most of what I know about it.

For G=Z/2, and L=sign rep, you have (S<sup>nL</sup>)<sub>hG</sub> = RP<sup>∞</sup>/RP<sup>n-1</sup>, and something similar holds for Z/p, and for the symmetric group Σ<sub>p</sub> (and perhaps for every group with periodic tate cohomology?)

If you have a decomposition of the form BG = hocolim BH, then you can pull your bundle over BG back to all the terms in the hocolim to get (S<sup>V</sup>)<sub>hG</sub> = hocolim (S<sup>V</sup>)<sub>hH</sub>.